# Static Initialization Order for Singletons

Tags: c++, static, singleton, static-variables, zero-initialization

So I'm reading that for [Zero Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) will initialize:

> Every named variable with static or thread-local storage duration that is not subject to constant initialization, before any other initialization

I am using a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) with the traditional private constructor and a static public method in which there is a local static singleton object which the method will be return.

My problem is that the class also has a static `vector` which is zero-initialized and it seems to be getting initialized *after* the singleton, meaning that I cannot interact with it. Is there something that governs this initialization order or is that simply implementation defined?

---

This is a simplification of what my code looks like:

```
class Foo {
    Foo(){ s_vec.push_back(13); }
public:
    static Foo& Get() {
        static Foo singleton;
        return singleton;
    }

    int Front() const { return s_vec.front(); }
    static vector<int> s_vec;
};
vector<int> Foo::s_vec;
```

I'm running into this problem because elsewhere in the code I'm initializing a static global variable like this and not getting 13: `static const auto element = Foo.Get().Front()`

Comment: Is there a need to make the vector static if the intent is to only have the one instance?

Comment: Note:  "error: cannot call member function ‘Foo& Foo::Get()’ without object."   I think you meant for this function to be static.

Comment: How did you determine " it seems to be getting initialized after the singleton "?  My trivial test suggests the Foo::s_vec exists before Foo::Get() is invoked.

Comment: "Foo& Get()" should be "static Foo& Get()", I assume?

Answer (score 0):

Constructor for global variables are executed before the start of main, but the order across compilation units is not specified.

The `Foo` constructor in your example should only be called once you call `Foo::Get`. If the first time you call it is in `main`, the static vector will be already initialized.

One situation, where you can run into the race that you describe is when you call `Foo::Get` in the initialization code of another global object, especially when the code is in another compilation unit.

But in a simple test like this here, the vector should always be initialized first and there will be no possible race:

```
class Foo {
    Foo() = default;
public:
    static Foo& Get() {
        static Foo singleton;
        return singleton;
    }
    static vector<int> s_vec;
};
vector<int> Foo::s_vec; // will be initialized before main

int main() {
  Foo::Get(); // --> triggers constructor call Foo::Foo
  return 0;
}
```

(I'm assuming `Foo::Get` is a static member in the singleton, otherwise you cannot instantiate it. But it does not make a difference conceptually.)

The problematic scenario could look like this:

```
// other file
struct Bar {
  Bar() { Foo::Get(); }
};
Bar bar; // global object
```

You have no control about the initialization order of `Foo::s_vec` (in the first compilation unit) and `bar` (in the second one).

Comment: I'm finally back from Christmas break! I've tried to clarify my question. I realized that my example did not clearly illustrate my problem: "The class also has a static vector which is zero-initialized and it seems to be getting initialized after the singleton, meaning that I cannot interact with it."